# Problems installing Rsymphony R package

Tags: r

I am trying to install Rsymphony on R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit) using
Windows 10.

I used this command:

```
install.packages("Rsymphony",type="source")
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
* installing *source* package 'Rsymphony' ...
** package 'Rsymphony' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c R_symphony.cc -o R_symphony.o
R_symphony.cc:12:27: fatal error: coin/symphony.h: No such file or directory
 #include <coin/symphony.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [R_symphony.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rsymphony'
* removing 'C:/Users/(…)/OneDrive - Department for Education/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rsymphony'
In R CMD INSTALL

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\(…)\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqsnyKC\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rsymphony", type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘Rsymphony’ had non-zero exit status

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using a company encrypted device.

Comment: What happens when you call `library(Rsymphony)`?! Have you tried installing in a fresh session?!

Comment: Error in library(Rsymphony) : there is no package called ‘Rsymphony’

Comment: Can't install. Issues with the package. See here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_Rsymphony.html

Comment: It seems Symphony (https://github.com/coin-or/SYMPHONY) is a prerequisite for this package. So one might first need to install symphony .   `SystemRequirements:  SYMPHONY libraries and headers`

Comment: Thank you, will try that